# Root component renders itself in router outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, ecmascript-5, angular2-components

Here is the structure of the angular 2 js(ES2015) project:

`src
├── app.js
├── components
│   ├── app
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── list
│   ├── loess
│   └── nw
├── modules
│   ├── app.module.js
│   └── index.js
├── routes
│   ├── app.routes.js
│   └── index.js
└── vendor.js`

I can't get at how to use router outlet tag. When I use it in a root component template, the tag makes this component renders twice in itself replacing router outlet tag. Sorry for tautology.
In addition to this, I have the error: 
`Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided must not be empty.`

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKj2L.png) with rendered content.

That is original stacktrace:

`angular.vendor.js:2723ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ angular.vendor.js:2723next @ angular.vendor.js:3586schedulerFn @ angular.vendor.js:3341SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ angular.vendor.js:4971SafeSubscriber.next @ angular.vendor.js:4926Subscriber._next @ angular.vendor.js:4880Subscriber.next @ angular.vendor.js:4844Subject.next @ angular.vendor.js:4451EventEmitter.emit @ angular.vendor.js:3341onError @ angular.vendor.js:3421onHandleError @ angular.vendor.js:3349ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular.vendor.js:24550Zone.runGuarded @ angular.vendor.js:24468_loop_1 @ angular.vendor.js:24709drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular.vendor.js:24717ZoneTask.invoke @ angular.vendor.js:24639
2016-10-15 22:29:01.285 angular.vendor.js:2723Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided must not be empty.
    at resolvePromise (angular.vendor.js:24762)
    at angular.vendor.js:24796
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular.vendor.js:24572)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (angular.vendor.js:3347)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular.vendor.js:24572)
    at Zone.runTask (angular.vendor.js:24488)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (angular.vendor.js:24699)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (angular.vendor.js:24639)ErrorHandler.handleError @ angular.vendor.js:2723next @ angular.vendor.js:3586schedulerFn @ angular.vendor.js:3341SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ angular.vendor.js:4971SafeSubscriber.next @ angular.vendor.js:4926Subscriber._next @ angular.vendor.js:4880Subscriber.next @ angular.vendor.js:4844Subject.next @ angular.vendor.js:4451EventEmitter.emit @ angular.vendor.js:3341onError @ angular.vendor.js:3421onHandleError @ angular.vendor.js:3349ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular.vendor.js:24550Zone.runGuarded @ angular.vendor.js:24468_loop_1 @ angular.vendor.js:24709drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular.vendor.js:24717ZoneTask.invoke @ angular.vendor.js:24639`

vendor.js:

```js
//Polyfill
import '../node_modules/core-js';
import '../node_modules/zone.js';
import '../node_modules/reflect-metadata';
import '../node_modules/system';
//Dependencies
import '../node_modules/rxjs';

// Core
import '../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser';
import '../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import '../node_modules/@angular/http';
import '../node_modules/@angular/router';
import '../node_modules/@angular/core';
import '../node_modules/@angular/common';
import '../node_modules/@angular/compiler';

//jQuery
import '../node_modules/jquery';
//Bootstrap
import '../node_modules/bootstrap';
//Bootstrap sidebar
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-layout';
//Bootstrap slider
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-slider';
```

app.js:

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from "./modules/app.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

app.module.js:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/core';

import { AppComponent, NwComponent, LoessComponent } from '../components';
import { routes } from '../routes';


export let AppModule = NgModule({
              imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
              declarations: [ AppComponent, NwComponent, LoessComponent ],
              bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
            }).Class({
              constructor() {
                console.log("Module started");
              }
            });
```

routes/app.routes.js:

```js
import { provideRoutes } from '../../node_modules/@angular/router'
import { AppComponent, LoessComponent, NwComponent } from '../components';

export let routes = [
   { path: 'loess', component: LoessComponent },
   { path: 'nw', component: NwComponent },
   { path: '', component: AppComponent }, // default route
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' } // 404
];

export let routesProvider = [
    provideRoutes(routes)
];
```

components/app/app.component.js:

```js
import '../../../node_modules/jquery';
import { Component, Inject } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/core';
import { BootstrapLayout, sidebar } from '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-layout';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/router';

export let AppComponent =
        Component({
          selector: 'ml-index',
          templateUrl: '/client/js/src/components/app/app.html',
        })
        .Class({
          constructor() {
            this.title = "App Component";

            console.log("AppComponent init");
            sidebar.init('#ml-sidebar');
          }
        });
```

app.html:

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I also use webpack@1.13.2. Here is the config file:

```js
var webpack = require("./node_modules/webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js',
        vendor: './src/vendor.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/ , loader: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader','css-loader','resolve-url'] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/, loader : 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'},
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' },
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname+'/bundle',
        filename: 'angular.[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: '../index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }),
    ]
};
```

P.S: After providing the working solution below, another error has appeared: `Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided must not be empty.`.

Here is the stacktrace description:

```
ErrorHandler.handleError    @   angular.vendor.js:2723
next    @   angular.vendor.js:3586
schedulerFn @   angular.vendor.js:3341
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @   angular.vendor.js:4971
SafeSubscriber.next @   angular.vendor.js:4926
Subscriber._next    @   angular.vendor.js:4880
Subscriber.next @   angular.vendor.js:4844
Subject.next    @   angular.vendor.js:4451
EventEmitter.emit   @   angular.vendor.js:3341
onError @   angular.vendor.js:3421
onHandleError   @   angular.vendor.js:3349
ZoneDelegate.handleError    @   angular.vendor.js:24550
Zone.runGuarded @   angular.vendor.js:24468
_loop_1 @   angular.vendor.js:24709
drainMicroTaskQueue @   angular.vendor.js:24717
ZoneTask.invoke @   angular.vendor.js:24639
2016-10-16 00:04:40.401
```

I solved it. Sorry, it was my fault. The error was produced by invalid syntax for routes in app.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because path '' is mapped to AppComponent.

With line

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

- You are telling Angular to render AppComponent when app starts.
- AppComponent starts and checks for the current route.
- Finds '' as the current route and AppComponent to load in the '' route. So creates another AppComponent and loads it into router outlet.

Solution:

Create something like HomePageComponent and map it to '' route.

Comment: Thanks a lot, pretty clear explanation. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. As we bootstrap a module, we must have some sort of an entry component which serves as a skeleton, don't we?

Comment: One more thing, now i have this issue: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided must not be empty. What would it be?

Comment: app.vendor.js throws it at line 2723. I can't post it here, so I'll add the stacktrace description to the question.